# Make self-reference by calculating fixed offset to the self's current address

Tags: rust

There is a [blog post about Rust](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2018/3/31/you-cant-rust-that/), where it is explained why Rust can't have self-referencing members.

There is an example with a slice storing offset and length instead of the pointer. I want to apply this to an object, where different parts need references to other parts.

Let's say the object looks like this:

```
struct Whole {
    struct Part0 { //members}
    struct Part1 {
        needs reference to part 0
    }
    struct Part2 { 
        needs reference to part 1 and part 0
    }
}
```

So, Whole can move around in memory (e.g., it can be stored in a vector). But in my scenario, Part1 and Part2 are always inside the Whole (and it is known at compile time). Also, Part1 always needs reference to the Whole it is currently part of. Thus Part 1 should be able to reference Part 0 by calculating its offset from Part 1's self.

I want to make a "reference" that stores offset of Part0 relative from Part1, so that Part1 can get a reference to Part0 by taking this offset from its 'self'.

Comment: What exactly is actually in each of the 3 parts? You might be able to just use indices instead.

Comment: code immitating protocols at different layers of network stack. [Here](https://github.com/effenok/d2sim.rs/blob/master/examples/network/simpledv/router.rs) is an example of Whole, but the way it is doing self-references is wrong and i am trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html):

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Part0 {}

struct Part1 {
    at_0: Rc<Part0>,
}

struct Part2 {
    at_0: Rc<Part0>,
    at_1: Rc<Part1>,
}

struct Whole {
    at_0: Rc<Part0>,
    at_1: Rc<Part1>,
    at_2: Rc<Part2>,
}

fn main() {
    let at_0 = Rc::new(Part0 {});
    let at_1 = Rc::new(Part1 { at_0: at_0.clone() });
    let at_2 = Rc::new(Part2 {
        at_0: at_0.clone(),
        at_1: at_1.clone(),
    });
    let _ = Whole { at_0, at_1, at_2 };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08c10208797417c514a142c0d86d7565)

Comment: this is a workaround that requires 3 heap allocations. i would prefer to not do this.

Comment: @Effie, I don't know what are your system constrains but they must be really tight if you cannot afford that. The solutions in the post you shared goes into unsafe territory. It is your choice.

Comment: a system programming language have to enable these kinds of low-level optimizations. if all your code is doing is heap allocations, there are better languages to code with.

Comment: @Effie: So then use `unsafe` to opt out of Rust's compile-time safety guarantees for this little bit of code in order to gain the same "superpowers" that you'd have in the "better languages" to which you refer?

Comment: if i knew how to do it, i would not be asking, right?

Comment: It does not matter how fast your program is if it's incorrect or vulnerable

Comment: @Effie, you can just use raw pointer if so wish to. But up to your own responsibility.  Rustlang leverages safety in its own means, but allow you to do whatever you want outside it too. Anyway you are free to use whatever tool you consider.

Comment: like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddf5e896ebfa3e67dd5cb1f7aa2a040f) except that i don't know how to do this. I want to figure out a solution that does not require pinning Whole (for the purpose of knowing how to do this, pinning is probably better)

Comment: @Effie: Perhaps [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13d566f7e8e6b304b45224e22b624f1f)?

Comment: @eggyal i will check it tomorrow

Comment: @eggyal That's also what I was thinking - you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @GManNickG:  I don’t know.  Since the layout is guaranteed to be constant, storing the offsets at run-time is both wasting memory and adding indirection; better to calculate them at compile-time and just use those.  But then, why are we bothering with any of this at all?  The motive is unclear, and I’m struggling to see a valid use case.  Likelihood is that this is the wrong way to solve whatever is the underlying problem.

Comment: because the use-case has creating objects of type "Whole" in one crate and managing their storage in another library crate. Progrmam logic dictates that each Whole will remain Whole all the time and parts will not exist outside of whole. Also, they need references to one-another. Any other kind of self-reference means that the logic that creates and manages storage of Wholes need to take into account that there can be self-references. And I don't want that.

Comment: and as @eggyal pointed out, object layout does not change, so storing self-references is also technically happening in run-time and is both wasting memory and adding indirection. i could probably just pass the reference to the Whole to each method in the part. But it will essentially achieve the same thing, just add another function parameter and code to handle it ...

Comment: i mean, unless i am misunderstanding something completely, this is almost exactly what the linker does, so this information shoud be obtainable at the compile time.

Comment: @Effie: I still am not sure I understand the problem.  If you statically know that you want to access `part1`, what’s wrong with `&self.part1`?  The compiler will calculate the offset at compile time and use an immediate, exactly as you describe.

Comment: i need part2 to be able to call part1, so self would be pointing at part2 and i need to get an offset to get to part1 or part0.

Comment: @Effie: okay, but that would necessarily have to be an `unsafe fn` as there’s no way it can know for certain that it’s part of a `Whole`.  Then again, you say these parts only ever exist in a `Whole`, which makes me wonder why you need to define them as separate `struct`s and not just merge their fields directly in `Whole`?

Comment: @Effie: or that, when you “need part2 to be able to call part1” those aren’t simply methods defined on `Whole`, which is the only time the operation can possibly be valid?

Comment: @eggyal you should post your answer, preferably with that comment that has 5 votes now. at the very least it is (a) answering the question (b) could be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> But in my scenario, Part1 and Part2 are always inside the Whole (and it is known at compile time).

In that case, there's no reason for `Part1` and `Part2` to be structs of their own: their fields could instead be defined directly on `Whole`.  Defining them as structs of their own might have made sense if that encapsulated some sub-behaviour, but the fact these parts need access to their siblings belies the suitability of such an approach.

If, for some reason, `Part1` and `Part2` must nevertheless remain as structs in their own right, then you could:

1. Pass a reference to the relevant sibling into any method that requires it:

   ```
   impl Part1 {
       fn do_something(&self, part0: &Part0) {
           // do whatever with self and part0
       }
   }
   ```

and/or

2. Implement relevant behaviours on `Whole` rather than the sub-part:

   ```
   impl Whole {
       fn do_something(&self) {
           // do whatever with self.part1 and self.part0
       }
   }
   ```

Of course, using `unsafe` code, it is nevertheless possible to discover the layout of a `struct` and access its members in the manner that you describe: I just don't see it being useful for the scenario described in this question. Nevertheless...

Ideally you'd want to embed knowledge of the layout of `Whole`'s members directly into your compiled code.  Unfortunately, because rustc does not directly provide means by which the layout of a `struct`'s members can be discovered during compilation, the only way this could be done is by manually calculating the position of each member.  However, as documented in [The Default Representation](https://rustwiki.org/en/reference/type-layout.html#the-default-representation) in The Rust Reference (emphasis added):

> Nominal types without a `repr` attribute have the default representation. Informally, this representation is also called the `rust` representation.
>
> **There are no guarantees of data layout made by this representation.**

Consequently, if `Whole` is using Rust's default representation, it is impossible to determine the layout of its members *during compilation* (however, if `Whole` uses [The C Representation](https://rustwiki.org/en/reference/type-layout.html#the-c-representation), which guarantees a particular layout of a `struct`'s members, one can manually calculate their positions at compile-time, which the [repr_offset](https://crates.io/crates/repr_offset) crate greatly simplifies); instead, the layout of `Whole`'s members can be determined at runtime:

```rust
use std::ptr;

impl Whole {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut me = Self { ... };

        unsafe {
            let addr_of_part0 = ptr::addr_of!(me.part0).cast::<u8>();
            let addr_of_part1 = ptr::addr_of!(me.part1).cast::<u8>();
            let addr_of_part2 = ptr::addr_of!(me.part2).cast::<u8>();

            me.part1.offset_to_part0 = addr_of_part0.offset_from(addr_of_part1);
            me.part2.offset_to_part0 = addr_of_part0.offset_from(addr_of_part2);
            me.part2.offset_to_part1 = addr_of_part1.offset_from(addr_of_part2);
        }

        me
    }
}
```

And then one can do:

```rust
impl Part1 {
    unsafe fn part0(&self) -> &Part0 {
        let addr_of_self  = ptr::addr_of!(*self).cast::<u8>();
        let addr_of_part0 = addr_of_self.offset(self.offset_of_part0);
        &*addr_of_part0.cast()
    }
}

impl Part2 {
    unsafe fn part0(&self) -> &Part0 {
        let addr_of_self  = ptr::addr_of!(*self).cast::<u8>();
        let addr_of_part0 = addr_of_self.offset(self.offset_of_part0);
        &*addr_of_part0.cast()
    }

    unsafe fn part1(&self) -> &Part1 {
        let addr_of_self  = ptr::addr_of!(*self).cast::<u8>();
        let addr_of_part1 = addr_of_self.offset(self.offset_of_part1);
        &*addr_of_part1.cast()
    }
}
```

Note that these functions are `unsafe` because they rely on you, the programmer, only invoking them when you *know* that the respective `offset_of_...` fields are valid offsets to the relevant type that can be dereferenced into a shared pointer with the same lifetime as `self`.  You likely will only ever be able to guarantee this when you are accessing `self` through an owning `Whole`, otherwise you could easily end up violating memory safety and triggering undefined behaviour—@Netwave's suggestion of using refcounted ownership is one thoroughly sensible way to avoid this risk.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some black magic of unsafe, and encapsulate the logic private to your struct promise SAFETY internally

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Part0 {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

struct Part1 {
    pdata0: NonNull<Part0>
}

struct Part2 {
    pdata0: NonNull<Part0>,
    pdata1: NonNull<Part1>,
}

struct Whole {
    p0: Part0,
    p1: Part1,
    p2: Part2,
}

impl Whole {
    fn new() -> Pin<Box<Self>> {
        // init Whole with NonNull
        let res = Self {
            p0: Part0 {
                data: vec![1, 2, 3],
            },
            p1: Part1 {
                pdata0: NonNull::dangling(),
            },
            p2: Part2 {
                pdata0: NonNull::dangling(),
                pdata1: NonNull::dangling(),
            },
        };

        // get boxed Whole
        let mut boxed = Box::pin(res);

        // get rawpointer of p0
        let ref0 = NonNull::from(&boxed.p0);

        // set p0 to p1.pdata0
        let mut_ref = (&mut boxed).as_mut();
        mut_ref.get_mut().p1 = Part1 {
            pdata0: ref0
        };

        let ref1 = NonNull::from(&boxed.p1);
        let mut_ref = (&mut boxed).as_mut();
        mut_ref.get_mut().p2 = Part2 {
            pdata0: ref0,
            pdata1: ref1,
        };

        boxed
    }

    fn use_p1(self: &Pin<Box<Self>>) {
        unsafe {println!("{:?}", self.p1.pdata0.as_ref())}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut h = Whole::new();
    h.use_p1();
}
```

Comment: these references use Whole's absolute address, require pinning Whole in memory, and everybody that does anything with Whole to be aware that it has self-references. i don't want this.

Comment: @Effie you should let user of Whole be aware it has self-references, because you don't know how they use it, they may use it in an async function only mulitthread environment

Comment: they use it by calling a well defined interface (trait).  and it is an event-driven simulator, so multithreading is most likely not gonna happen.